# refresh page with joomla component

Tags: model-view-controller, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a simple form in my tmpl/default.php:

```
<form id='AddForm' action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=addcam'); ?>" >
            <p>
            <label for="CamName">Name:
            </label>
            <input type="text" id="CamName" name="cam_name" />
            </p>
            <button type='submit' class='submit_cam' name='addcam' value='Add'>Add</button>
            <button type='reset' class='cancel_changes' name='cancel_changes' value='Cancel'>Cancel</button>
        </form>
```

In my controller.php file I'm trying to process the values:

```
function addcam()
{
    $add_name=JRequest::getString('cam_name');
    $model = &$this->getModel();
    $model->AddWebcam($add_name); //send to model to add to DB
}
```

In my model I just return the result of the query. With this implementation I just get routed to an empty page. I'd like to have it refresh the current page. Typically you do this with `action=""` but in my case I need it to route to the function called `addcam` in the controller. Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Looks pretty good, and I do this often, so it should work. Notice a couple odd items. I would wrap the php that builds the action in quotes(`action="<?php echo JRoute...; ?>"`). And the name of your input box differs from the string you request in the controller (`cam_name` v. `camname`).

Comment: @DavidFritsch Thanks! Stupid quotes. I've edited the question since that was my lameless. So maybe you know the answer to the next lame question :)

Comment: It looks like you are doing that. Can you do a `var_dump($add_name);` at the end of the function to see if you are getting into this function at all?

Comment: @DavidFritsch It returns the value someone entered for the name as expected. When the form is submitted it updates the DB as expected but I get a blank page with the url that looks like: `http://mysite.com/mypage/addcamera?cam_name=foo&addcam=Add` which is not right. It should just be `http://mysite.com/mypage/`

Comment: Hopefully that answer finishes this up for you. I also want to add this link for making a dedicated stack site for Joomla if you aren't aware: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common technique in Joomla when directing to the task is to have that function do a full redirect to a view at the end. This prevents a page refresh from trying to resubmit the data and leads to a cleaner url for the client. To do this, try the following:

```
function addcam()
{
    $add_name=JRequest::getString('cam_name');
    $model = &$this->getModel();
    $model->AddWebcam($add_name); //send to model to add to DB
    JFactory::getApplication()->redirect(JRoute::_(index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=whatever));
}
```

Obviously, update the JRoute bit to the url you actually need. You can also include a message if you would like (like "Saved!"): http://docs.joomla.org/JApplication::redirect/1.6